Vite multi page (HTML) and Tanstack Router
I'm working on a project that I'll need create 3 HTML files, and they will share the same JS source. The main reason is that I need 2 differents manifest files for each HTML, it will be a PWA application with different themes and logos.
So I created the project using Vite and Tanstack Router, and follow this instructions to create and build 3 differents HTML files.
It work normaly, but when I navigate to an internal route of Tanstack Router, and then refresh the browser, the server assume that the user is in the root page, not in the internal page on the internal route.
Here is a minimal reproducible example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-sttxb4
Here's a gif with the behavior:

Is there any workaround for this? What I'm doing wrong?

It seems to be something related to the dev server, the path /project-a/internal doesn't exists indeed, so when user opens this url directly the server redirect to the main index.html file.
Is there any way to "rewrite" this behavior in the dev server? Some middleware maybe. In production I can handle with it using nginx.

I found 2 topics with the same issue and some workarounds.
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2958
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/10707
